# "Module not Found" error on terminal window of Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I just finished downloading nodejs onto my computer. I created a javascript file stored on a folder in my desktop and when i attempt to run the JS code on visual studio terminal, i get the below stated error.I am certain that the file is stored in the correct location.

at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
at Module._load(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47{
Code: 'Module_not_found',
requireStack: []
}

The javascript file is named test.js. I opened the visual studio terminal window and at typed node test to run the javascript code written in the text editor window. i expected to run the console.log() statement

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the project folder on your Desktop. Have you opened the folder in VS code and then open the terminal in it?